# Panda: Count Intervall

Tags: python, pandas, count, between

I want to Count "D" (groupby "B" and "C"). And I want as an Output:
If my count is between 4 and 15: True
If my count is not between 4 and 15: False 
But my Code does not work:
df[df['A'] == True].groupby(['B', 'C'])[['D']].count() > 4 & < 15

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive` parameter:

```
s = df[df['A'] == True].groupby(['B', 'C'])['D'].count()

out = s.between(4, 15, inclusive=False)
print (out)
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'between'
Which import do I need?

Comment: @PythonBeast007 - there is change in my code `[['D']]` to `['D']` for return `Series`